# How do I stop a query within workbench?

Tags: mysql, indexoutofboundsexception

> We are sorry for the inconvenience but an unexpected exception has been raised by one of the MySQL Workbench modules. In order to fix this issue we would kindly ask you to file a bug report. You can do that by pressing the [Report Bug] button below.

Please make sure to include a detailed description of your actions that lead to this problem.

Thanks a lot for taking the time to help us improve MySQL Workbench!

The MySQL Workbench Team

Comment: What are you asking? Your title and "question" don't seem to be related at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean stop a query within workbench? If so:

[image]

Comment: stopping within workbench is different from stopping the query?